# Invoke WCF REST Service from ASP application

Tags: asp-classic

How to consume the WCF REST Service from classic asp application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added WCF project, organized it as WCF REST service, and then at classic asp application through jQuery send requests to it, and displayed responses.

Something similar is described 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WCF_JQUERY_ASMX.aspx
and 
http://geekswithblogs.net/Nettuce/archive/2009/10/18/wcf-jquery-rest-json-service.aspx